# How to export data with paging enabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to export data however it only extract the data in current paging. And I need to go to another paging to download another. Is there any where to download all data in the source?

Below is my aspx code:

<asp:datagrid id="dgAmount" Visible=false runat="server" CssClass="item01Nxx08" Width="100%" CellPadding="3"
BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" PageSize="50" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Vertical" ForeColor="Black">






<asp:BoundColumn DataField="No" SortExpression="No" HeaderText="No" visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Action" SortExpression="Action" HeaderText="Action"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="AppName" SortExpression="AppName" HeaderText="Approver Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="MIAmount" SortExpression="MIAmount" HeaderText="MI Amount"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="By" SortExpression="By" HeaderText="By">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Date" SortExpression="Date" HeaderText="Date">
</asp:BoundColumn>



</asp:DataGrid>

And below is my vb code:
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = True
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" & fileName & ".xls;")
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""

```
    'set the response mime type for excel
    'create a string writer
    Dim stringWrite As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
    'create an htmltextwriter which uses the stringwriter
    Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
    htmlWrite.WriteLine("<b><u>" & header & "</u></b><br /><br />")

    'instantiate a datagrid
    Dim dg As New DataGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable, dr As DataRow
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("No", GetType(Integer)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Action", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Approver Name", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MI Amount", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("By", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Date", GetType(String)))

    Dim tempDg As DataGrid = dgAmount
    For Each item As DataGridItem In tempDg.Items
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("No") = item.Cells(0).Text
        dr("Action") = item.Cells(1).Text
        dr("Approver Name") = item.Cells(2).Text
        dr("MI Amount") = item.Cells(3).Text
        dr("By") = item.Cells(4).Text
        dr("Date") = item.Cells(5).Text
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    dg.DataSource = dt
    dg.DataBind()
    dg.EnableViewState = False

    dg.GridLines = GridLines.None
    dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Size = 8
    dg.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
    dg.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
    dg.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
    dg.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    
    dg.ItemStyle.Font.Name = "Verdana"
    dg.ItemStyle.Font.Size = 8
    dg.ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top

    'bind the modified datagrid

    'tell the datagrid to render itself to our htmltextwriter
    dg.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
    'output the html
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString)
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn Paging off before bind/export. grid.AllowPaging = false;

Comment: hi, which part should i add that? because i tried but still cant get it

Comment: toward the top, try it before Dim tempDg As DataGrid = dgAmount